# wordpress erratic cache-like behavior

Tags: wordpress

I am having a really weird issue with one of my clients' WP installations.
Site behaves as if there was some kind of caching active. And it's the most noticeable in `wp-admin` area.

When I open plugin config page, what I see there does not correspond with what's really happening: wrong plugins are marked as active and some, that are active are not even visible (as if not even installed).

Hitting F5 usually helps and correct information is displayed, but when I go back to the dashboard (or any other page) and return to the plugin management, again wrong information is shown. If I click to enable/disable any of the present plugins, page is either not updating at all or is loading incorrect statuses.

What I have done so far to try to solve this:

- disabled all of the plugins
- switched to the "stock" theme (Twenty Seventeen)
- changed the language to EN (oddily enough, when toggling plugins, language switched back to the previous one)
- checked nginx configs for any cache-related settings and disabled those
- checked for presence of Varnish / Redis etc (not present)
- disabled OPcache
- checked whether the site is served via CDN (is not)
- checked if `wp-config.php` is containing settings like `define('WP_CACHE', true);` (it does, but commented out)
- switched PHP versions
- changed PHP workers
- disabled nginx to Apache proxying
- wiped the "plugin" directory clean

Nothing seems to be helping.

Other websites, hosted on that server, do not experience any issues. Has anyone experienced anything like that? Any ideas how to fix it?

Here you can see "live" what I mean:

[image: https://imageshack.com/a/img923/7599/RdhFO2.gif]

Comment: That's odd. Maybe your set up has been corrupted somehow? Did you try reinstalling WordPress already? (Dashboard > Updates > Re-install Now).

Comment: Does the same happen when you keep your devtools open with "disable cache" checked? (exactly like that in Chrome, other browsers may vary some)

Comment: I didn't think of reinstalling. Unfortunately that does not help (just tried). When I go to plugins and re-activate - for example - Gravity Forms, I see Autoptimize highlighted as active o_O. Yes, @René with browser cache disabled it happens too.

Comment: That's really bizarre. If there used to be a caching functionality, perhaps there are some remnants of it? Re-saving permalinks would flush the rewrite rules... I have no idea why that would help but who knows? Is it being served by Cloudflare? Try ctrl+F5 or shift+F5 or cmd+F5 depending on your set up to refresh and clear the browser cache. No other ideas, good luck bud.

Comment: @Shoelaced I forgot to write it, but I did flush permalinks. I also installed a plugin called "Rewrite Rules Inspector" to see if there is maybe something weird going on. But no luck there as well. All combinations on hard refresh had also been tried: Ctrl+F5, Ctrl+Shift+R. It is also not served by Cloudflare (or any other CDN). I have also restarted the whole web stack and.... no avail <,<

Comment: I dunno, man. At that point I'd probably just do a piecemeal migration - set up a fresh WP install, verify that the problem isn't happening, move over and activate the plugins, verify, move over the wp-content, verify, move over and activate the theme, verify, drop the database and migrate over the old one, verify. If that doesn't work I suggest exorcism, haha.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had issues like I did, here is what I did to finally solve it:

- wiped all server-side cache
- wiped wp cache files
- uninstalled all the plugins
- uninstalled the style
- reinstalled WP
- rebuild all user configs / permissions etc
- reinstalled style
- reinstalled all the plugins

ta-daaa!

it's working now. What a mess this was... o_O